# Symfony: Entity with flexible relations and it's (sub-)forms - how to design?

Tags: php, database, symfony, oop, symfony-forms

I have a `User`-Entity with the very base information. The `User` should be able to share more detailed data in a profile. There are different `ProfileSet`s for different `User`s.

In this example I try to keep it simple: `ProfileSet_A` is a profile with personal information, `ProfileSet_B` stores anonymous data.

A `User` can only have one `ProfileSet`.

**Entities** (Pseudocode)

```
// table: users
class User {
    protected $id,
              $email, 
              $username, 
              $password; // ...
}

// table: - none - 
class ProfileSet {
    protected $id,
              $name; // ...
}

// table: profileset_a
class ProfileSet_A extends ProfileSet {
    protected $firstname,
              $lastname,
              $morePrivateStuff; // ...
}

// table: profileset_b
class ProfileSet_B extends ProfileSet {
    protected $anyAnonymousStuff; // ...
}

// table: user_has_profileset
class UserHasProfileSet {
    protected $user,       // relation to User
              $profileSet; // relation to ProfileSet_A OR ProfileSet_B
}
```

**Form, ProfileSet_A**

```
username:            [ textfield ]
email:               [ textfield ]
firstname:           [ textfield ]
lastname:            [ textfield ]
morePrivateStuff:    [ textfield ]
```

**Form, ProfileSet_B**

```
username:            [ textfield ]
email:               [ textfield ]
anyAnonymousStuff:   [ textfield ]
```

**Problems**

1. `UserHasProfileSet` should relate to `User $user` and a `ProfileSet`, which could be an instance of `ProfileSet_A` or `ProfileSet_B`. I'd like to have just the field `$profileSet` instead of `$profileSet_A`, `$profileSet_B`, ...
2. I'd like to edit the `User` and it's `ProfileSet` (A or B) within the same form.

**Question**

How to solve the problems in a clean way? I'm open to best-practice alternatives. Maybe I'm thinking in a wrong way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read about [Doctrine inheritance](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)? Or you do not use `Doctrine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Doctrine` in your project you can archive this with the [Doctrine inheritance](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), for example with `MappedSuperClass`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    // other fields

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ProfileSet")
     */
    private $profile;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"a" = "ProfileSet_A", "b" = "ProfileSet_B"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile_sets")
 */
class ProfileSet
{
    // common properties
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile_sets_a")
 */
class ProfileSetA extends ProfileSet
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="profile_sets_b")
 */
class ProfileSetB extends ProfileSet
{
    // ...
}
```

In this case Doctrine will create 3 tables: `profile_sets` which will contain common fields and the type of profile, `profile_sets_a` and `profile_sets_b` will contain specific fields. When you fetch your `User` with `$profile` property, Doctrine will automatically map the needed Object.

As you have only one `ProfileSet` entry for each `User` it's not necessary to define extra `UserHasProfileSet` entity and you can just set `OneToOne` association directly. But you can do it the same way if you have to.